# Cap deploy error find_file_in_path: no such file foud

Tags: capistrano, capifony

I'm using capyfony + symfony2.

cap deploy

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:183:in `find_file_in_load_path': no such file to load --  (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:171:in `load_from_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from Capfile:3:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue. By investigating, I tried to put:

```
puts Gem.find_files('symfony2.rb')
```

In my *Capfile* file, as mentioned on https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/190. Yet, it returns nothing. I think I miss this file. How can I get it?

**Edit :**

After more investigating, I finally find the solution.

I used a Capfile for Capifony 2.1.16. It seems the new version of Capifony (2.2) requires some changes in the Capfile file. With the following it should work:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
Dir['vendor/bundles/*/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |bundle| load(bundle) }
load Gem.find_files('capifony_symfony2.rb').last.to_s
load 'app/config/deploy'
```

Comment: Following the upgrade notes is what fixed it for me: https://github.com/everzet/capifony/blob/9da207a4b0f15c65d2b4f6646d855bb49ff52b17/UPGRADE.md

Comment: The right answer is: please read the UPGRADE file as @ampt said. (https://github.com/everzet/capifony/blob/master/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: Got the same issue with Capifony 2.4, any thought ? (ruby is 1.8.7 and Capistrano is 2.9.0)